# Version of the Dirichlet Problem in two dimensions

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, harmonic-functions

Let $D:= B(0,R)$\ $B(0,1)$ for $R>1$ such that $\Delta H=0$ in $D$, $H=0$ on $\partial B(0,1)$, and $H=1$ on $B(0,R)$.

I would like to find an explicit solution to this problem, however I am unsure how to go about it. Since the laplacian is zero, my first thought was that I could use the harmonic function for the two-dimensional Brownian motion, that is, $H_2(x)=\log(\|x\|)$, but I don't see how this works here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are almost there.  Note that $H_2=0$ on the inner circle, which is good, and $H_2=\log R$ on the outer circle, which isn't quite what we want.  So what can you do to fix this?

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry, I am still not seeing what we can do.

Comment: Remember the Laplacian is a linear operator.  What do you know about the kernel of linear operators?

Comment: Do you intend the boundary conditions to be that $H=1$ on the complement of $B(0,R)$ and that $H=0$ on the closure of $B(0,1)$? (If $H$ vanishes on the full boundary of $D$ then $H$ will vanish throughout $D$ (assuming $H$ continuous on the closure of $D$).)

Comment: @JohnDawkins I just made a small correction. $H=0$ on the boundary of $B(0,1)$, not on the boundary of D. Otherwise, according to the notes that I am reading with this exercise, $H=1$ on $B(0,R)$, not the complement.

Comment: But then $H$ is both $0$ and $1$ on the sphere of radius $1$ (the intersection of $B(0,R)$ and $\partial B(0,1)$).